# how to make single view of ASP.Net MVC windows authenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I have created my website in ASP.Net MVC 5. 
My entire website is publicly accessible but i want just one view to be accessible only to particular set of users. In short I want to apply windows authentication to one view/controller of my website. So if somebody enters 'http://computerName/searchcardholder/' this URL it should show the view to only few users.
Can any one help me in this please ?

Comment: Can you try this link and let us know how it goes ?
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/windows-authentication-in-mvc4-with-iis-express/

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the authorize attribute to the action that serves the view, supports all AD structures.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="your role")]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(){ return View();}
}
```

Comment: I do not want to enable windows authentication in IIS as it will enable it to entire application. I just want to apply authentication to single view. 
Please can someone help ???

Comment: If windows auth is not activated you will never get credentials for anything without rolling your own authentication process or going with something like OAUTH.
You can activate it and allow all and anon users to the rest of the application only using the tag to restrict access to this one specific view. 
Your actual problem is that you are trying to have a public app with no login process that somehow restricts access to certain users when you never know who anyone is....there must be a login somewhere for this to be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. 
Basically, I am working on eCommerce website so the website should be available publicly. But there is only one view which should only be accessed to the vendor users or particular set of users and that is from Windows authenticated. 
You are right that I have to make the website windows authenticated. But if i will make 'Windows Authentication' as enabled will the site accessible to the outside world. 
Can you paste some psudo code so that I can search on it over the internet.

Comment: Because its public AD actually wont do you any good (users will not have AD creds). Your going to have to go the roll your own or go with an OAUTH/identity framework or similar route and create a user registration and login system before you can even get this far. You'll have to open another question to get answers on that but it is an extremely broad subject so you need to do your own research first, non of this is trivial... https://oauth.net/ http://www.asp.net/identity